# Gyroscope Ionic Angular Error with constructor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, gyroscope, devicemotion

I implemented the gyroscope from https://github.com/NeoLSN/cordova-plugin-gyroscope and then, when i imported it as an Angular i got

Cannot find name 'constructor'.
And other errors concerning the import below from https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/gyroscope.

Does anyone have a complete version?

```
    import { Gyroscope, GyroscopeOrientation, GyroscopeOptions } from '@ionic-native/gyroscope/ngx';

    constructor(private gyroscope: Gyroscope) { }

    ...

    let options: GyroscopeOptions = {
    frequency: 1000
    }

     this.gyroscope.getCurrent(options)
    .then((orientation: GyroscopeOrientation) => {
    console.log(orientation.x, orientation.y, orientation.z, orientation.timestamp);
    })
    .catch()


    this.gyroscope.watch()
    .subscribe((orientation: GyroscopeOrientation) => {
    console.log(orientation.x, orientation.y, orientation.z, orientation.timestamp);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to import in `app.module.ts`:

```
import { Gyroscope, GyroscopeOrientation, GyroscopeOptions } from '@ionic-native/gyroscope/ngx';
```

2. Add into **ngmodule**:

```
@NgModule({
   ...
   ...
   ...
  providers: [....,Gyroscope],
})
```

After this steps you should be done.